# Spearman's rho for tied ranks

Tags: statistics, correlation

I know how to prove that Spearman's $ \rho / r_s$ can be written as $r_s = 1-\frac{6\sum\limits_{i=1}^nd_i^2}{n(n^2-1)}$ with $d_i=R(x_i)-R(y_i)$ when there are no ties.

Now I came across the formula for tied ranks: $r_s = 1-\frac{6\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^nd_i^2+\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\frac{t_j^3-t_j}{12}\right)}{n(n^2-1)}$ where $t_j$ represents the $j^{th}$ tie length. (I found this formula at the following link: https://www.onlinemath4all.com/spearman-rank-correlation-coefficient.html )

Another version of this formula would be $r_s = \frac{\frac{n^3-n}{6}-\sum d_i^2 - \sum T_x -\sum T_y}{\sqrt{(\frac{n^3-n}{6}-2\sum T_x)(\frac{n^3-n}{6}-2\sum T_y)}}$ with $\sum T_x = \frac{\sum t_i^3-t_i}{12}$ and $\sum T_y = \frac{\sum t_i^3-t_i}{12}$ where $t_i$ is the number of groups the random variables $X$ and $Y$ tie respectively. (I found this formula at the following link: http://webspace.ship.edu/pgmarr/Geo441/Lectures/Lec%2011%20-%20Spearman%27s%20and%20Cramer%27s%20Correlation.pdf )

I'm unable to prove either of both formulas for tied ranks. I tried to rewrite $R(x_i)$ in a different way but always failed to obtain the formula.
My question therefore is if anyone has a hint on how to prove any of the two formulas or maybe if someone has a complete proof?

Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you tell us the source of this formula?

Comment: Sure, I don't think it well help much for proving the formula, but I found it here: https://www.onlinemath4all.com/spearman-rank-correlation-coefficient.html                         Another source would be the following: http://webspace.ship.edu/pgmarr/Geo441/Lectures/Lec%2011%20-%20Spearman%27s%20and%20Cramer%27s%20Correlation.pdf

Comment: Your post is not self-contained, since you do not define $t_j$. Again, the sum involving $t_j$ does not look the same as given in the first link. So, please edit your post to add the source, define $t_j$ and update the formula for $r_s$. I am more familiar with the formula in the second link.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I'm not used to writing a lot of questions on stack exchange, but is it better in this way? As I understand it the $t_i$'s are tie lengths, so if for instance $X = \{1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5\}$ then $t_1=2$ and $t_2=3$ since $1$ exists twice and $5$ three times and thus the ranks in this example should be $R_X = \{1.5,1.5,3,4,7,7,7\}$.

Comment: Some passive-aggressive neckbeard anonymously downvoted your question. Sorry for that, I upvoted.